# Can I misty step while carrying a willing/unconscious creature so we both teleport?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple

In my case, the creature is a player who is doing death saving throws and the intention is to teleport both, the carrier and the carried.

Note: The creature is being carried, so the answer in "[Can a player misty step with another player or NPC or creature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/65621/can-a-player-misty-step-with-another-player-or-npc-or-creature)" doesn't apply as it does only to grappling (which was also in the question next to "carried" but removed then when seen the existance of an answer to that case).

Comment: I believe that this is a duplicate. The carried player is a Creature, and not an object and both are asking "If I am holding another creature, can I misty step?" If you are asking about an Object (dead creature), this would NOT be a duplicate.

Comment: There's a difference between grappling and carrying, many users have talked before about carrying a living creature (when I say carrying here, I include pushing/dragging/lifting depending on if the weight exceeds the carrying limit but not the pushing/dragging/lifting limit). See https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117423/does-carrying-dragging-a-willing-unconscious-creature-cause-half-movement-as-per answer.

Comment: That's the difference that makes this question a duplicate. It's the creature/object difference that matters here - and other creatures being 'carried' are still other creatures and fall under those rules.

Comment: Reading the question and answer mine is supposed to be duplicating, I see they refer to Grappling a willing or unconscious creature, not to carrying it (which is said to be possible in https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117423/does-carrying-dragging-a-willing-unconscious-creature-cause-half-movement-as-per). I'm not talking about the grappling rules, but the carrying rules, which are said to be possible to be used by users like guildsbonty.

Comment: @Zorsal I think the main point about it being a duplicate is that the other question is asking about creatures in general. Whether a creature is willing, unconscious, grappled, etc does not matter. Misty Step having a range of self means it affects only 1 creature: the caster. Your question ends up being a subset of that question (only about unconscious carried creatures). Note that [duplicates are not bad](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) and this does not penalize you in any way. This contribution is appreciated!

Comment: I just made this question since (as far as I remember) something carried is considered part of your inventory and spells with self range (as invisibility or misty step) affect you and anything you are carrying. If it affects anything you carry, does it affect a living creature you carry? The rules never say a creature you carry is considered part of your inventory (but also doesn't say the opposite).

Comment: Related on [What are the rules around picking up and carrying bodies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103496/what-are-the-rules-around-picking-up-and-carrying-bodies)

Comment: So... then self range spells affect you (and your sexy body) as well as your inventory, but not those living creatures you hold. So, if you have Steve, your tiny cute squirrel, inside your pocket, and use misty step, Steve will just find himself in the air falling from where there should be your pocket, am I wrong?

Comment: @Zorsal if Steve is a creature (as squirrels tend to be) then the answer to duplicate question apply to it as well.

Comment: Thanks, I will have this into account if I ever carry a little pet. And does solve my question too.